# Blender Cycles network egpu rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

i have some extra eGPUs on other machines in the network, i'm on Macosx, and i was wondering if there's a way to force Cycles to use these extra cards. I'm used to Octane which is great for this, but i'm not use if it's possible, or it WILL be possible, with Cycles. 
Thanks a lot

Marco